# What is the core difference between ant-contrib's for and foreach?

Tags: ant, scripting

What is the main difference between for and for each. 
I am working with websphere mqfte to transfer files using ant scripts.

I need my files to renamed and send to another folder as below :

eg:  src : `\src\*.txt`  the files in destination should be `\dest\kk_*.cpp` (The * indicates the filename. Need all the files to to renamed as follows).

Can anyone help me on this???.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between for and foreach task from antcontrib =

for uses sequential like macrodef whereas
foreach opens a new project scope for each iteration - like other tasks as
ant, antcall, and subant.

That means because of performance issues the use of for task should be favored.

For your renaming problem => you should use copy or move task with
a nested mapper as already stated by other fellows.
What's the reason to act against standard ant usage !?

btw. because antcontrib development seems to be dead - last release back in 2006 :
there's a new ant addon with similar features => [ant flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task with a glob or regexp [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html). Don't know what for and for each have to do with this question, though.

Comment: The thing is i need to perform this renaming without using copy and mapper tasks.

Comment: For posterity - using ant-contrib but not using copy and mapper tasks is silly. This answer is the best way to deal with the example (though the question seems to be entirely unrelated to the example).

Answer (score 0):

The for and foreach tasks are not part of core Ant, most likely they are the ones in the ant-contrib collection.

According to the ant-contrib [`for` task docs](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html):

> This task is the same as the `<foreach>`
>   task, except that
>
> ```
> * it uses a nested sequential for each iteration; and
> * it implements an additional "keepgoing" attribute.
> ```
>
> `<for>` makes use of ant's macrodef
>   task, so the @{} notation is used for
>   parameter substition.

Comment: Clayton . Can you please suggest me a way to perform this renaming without using mapper task.

Comment: Maybe, but why can't you use a copy with a mapper then call fte:copy for the renamed files - have you tried and hit a problem?

Comment: It works fine clayton. But according to my requirement i cant create any staging in the source end or destination end.

Comment: There are some jobs which starts when any cpp file is detected in the source end. The same way some jobs starts when any txt file is detected in destination end. So i cannot stage it anywhere and rename.